# SQL Group By return multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by, dynamic-sql

I have a issue where i need to get the total count of some data from a table

there are 3 types of grouping i need to perform
1. 1 grouping should be on partner
2. 1 grouping on country
3. 1 grouping on date

I have a table like so

```
PartnerId, CountryId, Date
  1           2       10-01-2017
  1           2       10-01-2017
  1           3       10-01-2017
  1           1       10-01- 2013
```

I want the return data set to be

```
1     2    10-01-2017 - total 2
1     3    10-01-2017 - total 1
1     1    10-01-2013 - total 1
```

Here is what i tried for the partner grouping, but i get incorrect values and duplicate with bad total count

```
  ELSE IF(@partnerId > 0 AND @CountryId = 0 AND @InvoiceMonth IS NULL)
        BEGIN
             SET @sql = @sql + ' INSERT INTO #FinalBucket2
          SELECT  b.PartnerId, Null, b.CountryId, NULL, a.Local_Closed_Calendar_Month, b.Total
         FROM #DataBucket2 a WITH(NOLOCK),
          ( SELECT  PartnerId, CountryId, count(*) Total
         FROM #DataBucket2 WITH(NOLOCK)
         GROUP BY PartnerId, CountryId ) b
         WHERE a.PartnerId = b.PartnerId 
       '
        END
```

Here if i pass PartnerId then the grouping should be by partner.
If i pass countryId and no PartnerId & InvoiceMonth then grouping should be on country.
and if i pass only InvoiceMonth then the grouping should be on invoiceMonth only

Comment: You did somewhat a self-join just to get a.Local_Closed_Calendar_Month?

Comment: yes, #DataBucket2 contains the master data of all the columns i need and hence i did it. is there a way around it ?

Comment: Why don't you just add that column in this select, SELECT  PartnerId, CountryId, count(*) Total FROM #DataBucket2 WITH(NOLOCK) GROUP BY PartnerId, CountryId?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar: i guess your right, now if i want to group by Country what do i do?

so if i want something like country X all parters all dates = total count

Comment: Can you provide a.Local_Closed_Calendar_Month on your sample data above, please? TY

Comment: Provide also a sample data and expected result for this "if i want to group by Country what do i do? so if i want something like country X all parters all dates = total count".

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar : the same data is in my initial post

`PartnerId, CountryId, Local_Closed_Calendar_Month 
  1           2                   10-01-2017
  1           2                   10-01-2017
  1           3                   10-01-2017
  1           1                   10-01- 2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the below SQL. This will group by partnerid, countryid, and local_closed_calendar_month. If you want to group it by country then all partners, then you just need to switch them.

```
SELECT partnerId,
       countryId,
       local_closed_calendar_month,
       COUNT(*) Total
  FROM #DataBucket2
 GROUP BY partnerId, 
          countryId,
          local_closed_calendar_month
```

Comment: Thank you, i think i had it the first time, just confused myself lol